# How to build my app, need guidelines

Tags: java, android, applet, server

I trying to build a very small android app, just for my own use and knowledge, I've learned Java a few years ago, but now and i need some help.
the app will use Google maps and will send the location to a server (can someone recommend on one?), that's all for the this app.

The main thing I would like to build is a screen which I can see all the users in it, this screen is planning to run on a PC, and that's the part i need you guys.

How should I build this screen? Is it supposed to be an applet? Maybe a Web application? Could it be something else? What should be the layout if I want to present the map on most of the screen and some buttons and text on the side/bottom? and where can i find examples and stuff on this subject?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please go through http://developer.android.com/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest for you would be to make a simple HTTP java servlet. If you don't have a lot of experience, I would recommend using amazon's SimpleDB as your database, and hosting your servlet on one of aws' free services. You can find documentation online on how to manipulate your simpleDB from your java servlet, and how to talk to the servlet from your android client.This would be a good experience to learn about client-server stacks and http methods.

There are loads of ways to do this, but I recommend this as the simplest. I currently do something similar using a django framework (python) and a postgresql database hosted on heroku.